# Get difference between the two arrays in separate arrays ,AddedList and RemovedList in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am new to typescript, and i want find a right way to solve my problem.
So i have two arrays A and B, i need to find a difference between two arrays relative to array A and return a result in separate arrays what was addArray and what was removedArray
For example:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4];
B = [1, 5, 6, 7];
addArray =[5,6,7]
removedArray =[2,3,4]
```

Looking for fast and elegant way

Comment: Shouldn't `removedArray` be `[2,3,4]`?  Am I misreading your requirements?

Comment: This has been solved before.  E.g., Lodash has `difference` and `intersection`, which would be where I'd start my research.

Comment: @Doug Coburn  yes it's, I will update

Comment: can `A` or `B` have duplicate elements?  What should be the behavior in that case?  Does order matter?

Comment: No duplicates, order doesn't matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const A = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const B = [1, 5, 6, 7];
const difference = (left, right) => {
  let a = new Set(left);
  let b = new Set(right);
  return [...a].filter(x => !b.has(x))
}
const addArray = difference(B, A);
const removedArray = difference(A, B);

console.log({ addArray, removedArray });
```

References:

- 2ality: [ECMAScript 6 sets: union, intersection, difference](http://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-set-operations.html)
- MDN: [Set : Implementing basic set operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Implementing_basic_set_operations)

Comment: Thank you! I am not agree with someone who set that question as duplicate..good to know that javascript supports sets